# MailChimp API only lists "code your own" templates

Tags: mailchimp

I have a mailchimp account with 4+ different templates. Some were created using the "base" option in the web interface and some were created using the "code your own" option. When I try to list my templates using the API

```
curl -d apikey=######## https://us8.api.mailchimp.com/2.0/templates/list
```

I only get templates that were created using the "code your own" option.

```
{
  "user":[
    {"id":########,"name":"Code Your Own Template 1", ...}, 
    {"id":########,"name":"Code Your Own Template 2", ...}
  ],
  "gallery":[],
  "base":[]
}
```

Is that just the way it is? Is there no way to access templates that were created using the "basic" or "theme" options via the API?

Comment: It says right in the API documentation, http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/templates/list.php: _“user – boolean – **Custom templates** for this user account. Defaults to true.”_ And it also says there, that `base` templates _“are now all saved Drag & Drop templates”_  … so maybe you want to try the `filter`-option `include_drag_and_drop`?

Comment: Yep. Thanks. It was the `include_drag_and_drop` filter option.